# Strange behaviour with core data entity

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have this portion of code

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemID:NSManagedObjectID = self.frc!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath).objectID!
    let entity:Entity = self.frc?.managedObjectContext.existingObjectWithID(itemID, error: nil) as Entity

    if entity.completed {
        entity.completed = false
    } else {
        entity.completed = true
    }

    println(entity.completed)

}
```

when the event occurs tableView performs scroll to top animation any ideas?

Comment: the problem is with this line of code `entity.completed = false`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably updating your managed object array somehow (not shown), perhaps via some delegate method. Most likely, you are calling `tableView.reloadData()` somewhere to update the displayed data. That automatically reloads the entire table view and will scroll to the top.

Instead, just update the cell in question with `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(rowAnimation:)` documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

Maybe you sorting routine (not shown) is sorting by the `completed` attribute. Then the scrolling might be expected behavior.

*NB: It seems odd that you keep an array of IDs as the `dataSource`. It would be just as efficient to just have an array of objects, due to the faulting behavior of Core Data. Better even, you should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a table view - you get lots of cool behavior for free and are guaranteed to have the best solution for performance and memory management.*

Comment: i think its an iOS 8 bug it happens when I'm using self sizing cells with height for row everything works fine

Comment: @Mundi: `tableView.updateCellsForRowsAtIndexPaths()` sounds interesting but I cannot find that function?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `reload`. Corrected and linked to documentation.